# Move both branch tips when merging

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there an easy way to move both branch tips to the merge commit?

Initial situation:

```
A--B <-- master
 \
  C  <-- dev
```

Situation after

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

assuming merge commit D is created without conflicts:

```
A--B--D <-- master
 \  /
  C  <-- dev
```

Desired situation:

```
A--B--D <-- master, dev
 \  /
  C
```

Comment: Why do you want that? If you intend to continue working on dev a rebase might make more sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's a bit complicated, but is has to do with integrating a versioning tool into an existing project. I need to harmonize the two branches for an initial base version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply merge `master` into `dev` :

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

---

If you want to be extra sure that no extra manual operation got in the way, add the `--ff-only` option :

```
git merge --ff-only master
```

This option will make sure `dev` will not create an extra merge commit on top of `master`, only a fast forward to `master` will be accepted.